# ManagementObjectSearcher WMIquery very slow

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a .NET 6.0 code I run repeatedly to monitor the CPU on a machine and send statistics to a dashboard server:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var processorQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher().WMIquery("select * from Win32_Processor");
Log(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); // !!! 2 to 10 seconds!

// now process the results
var processors = new JArray();
foreach (var processorMO in processorQuery) {
  var name = processorMO["Name"]?.ToString() ?? "";
  var addressWidth = Double.Parse(processorMO["AddressWidth"]?.ToString() ?? "-1");
  if (name.IndexOf(addressWidth.ToString()) != -1) name = $"{name} x{addressWidth}";
  var maxClockSpeedGHz = Double.Parse(processorMO["MaxClockSpeed"]?.ToString() ?? "-1000") / 1000.0;
  if (name.IndexOf(maxClockSpeedGHz.ToString()) != -1) name = $"{name} {maxClockSpeedGHz}GHz";
  var numberOfCores = Double.Parse(processorMO["NumberOfCores"]?.ToString() ?? "-1");
  name = $"{name} {numberOfCores}cores";
  name = name.Replace("CPU ", " ").Replace(" M ", " M").Replace(" @ ", " ");
  name = string.Join(" ", name.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)); // replace multiple spaces with single
  int loadPercentage = (int)Double.Parse(processorMO["LoadPercentage"]?.ToString() ?? "-1");
  processors.Add(new JObject() { { "Name", name }, { "LoadPercentage", loadPercentage } });
}
```

My issue is that the call to `WMIquery` is *extremely* slow .. from 2.5 to 10 seconds!

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? is there a way to get this information faster ?

(PS which other tags are useful here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GetSystemTimes which gives you for all cores the Idle, Kernel and User time.
If you do this e.g. every second you can calculate overall CPU utilization by yourself in a much more efficient way.

See

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getsystemtimes

and

- [C# System CPU Usage and syncing with Windows Task Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216645/c-sharp-system-cpu-usage-and-syncing-with-windows-task-manager)

Answer (score 2):

It's slow because you're doing `select *` which includes such things as `LoadPercentage` which isn't something that WMI acquires from its database, it's real-time info that's tested at the point of querying and takes *at least* a second to complete and give an accurate assessment of the load. Since it seems you actually need `LoadPercentage` there's nothing much you can do other than just wait. I would not worry about this at all, maybe focus more on the CPU/IO penalty inhibited by each query.

Comment: Thanks ! Other the time it takes is this query expensive in terms of CPU load or memory ?

Comment: @kofifus That's the part you should test more thoroughly. I think it's OK but it's mostly used for an odd one-time report or a quick-check. For periodic CPU load analysis we usually use 3rd party devops tools that integrate with Grafana or perf counters that come with Windows ([something like this](https://michaelscodingspot.com/performance-counters/)).